# creating a custom constraint in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using sql on a C# application and my table consists of stock quotes. The columns that I'm concerned with are called Symbol and Date. What I'm trying to do is restrict a row from adding to the table if both the symbol and date exist already in a separate row.

For example if I already have a row for GOOG and today's date then if I try adding a row with that matching information then it either gets denied or updates the existing row with the new information. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.StockDailyData AS Target
USING (VALUES ('<your id value>', '<symbol>', '<Market>', '<Open>',
               '<High>', '<Low>', '<Close>', '<Volume>', '<AdjustedClose>', '<Date>')
       AS Source (ID, Symbol, Market, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, AdjustedClose, Date)
ON Target.Symbol = Source.Symbol AND Target.Date = Source.Date
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Market = Source.Market,
       Target.High = Source.High,
       Target.Low = Source.Low,
       Target.Close = Source.Close,
       Target.Volume = Source.Volume,
       Target.AdjustedClose = Source.AdjustedClose,
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (ID, Symbol, Market, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, AdjustedClose, Date) 
       VALUES (Source.ID, Source.Symbol, Source.Market, Source.Open, 
               Source.High, Source.Low, Source.Close, Source.Volume, 
               Source.AdjustedClose, Source.Date
```

By using `MERGE` you can set logic for what to do if the record already exists - in your case you would update the new quote information.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need but I'm unsure about how to edit to match my needs. I have hardly worked with databases before. My column names are ID, Symbol, Market, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, AdjustedClose, and Date and if Symbol and Date both match my code and are in the database already then I want to update that row instead. How would I do this?

Comment: If you give me the table names too, I can try to give you a command that will work for you.

Comment: It is just one table in my database and it is called dbo.StockDailyData

Comment: I hope the update is clear but I suspect you may need to make some adjustments. The values in the "<>" are there for you to replace with your data (from C# variables probably). You might also need to remove references to the 'ID' column if that is set as an IDENTITY column (auto incrementing column...).

Comment: Yes the ID column is set as an identity column but I'm really not sure how to place the C# variables in this statement because I was under the assumption that I run the query once on the database and it gets saved or something for all future uses for that table. Does that make sense? I'm inserting data into the table using a tableadapter and a dataset in my C# code

Comment: Would I just use the Dataset.merge method instead?

Comment: Not sure about that method. This statement is a replacement for using `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. It would definitely be worth checking out Dataset.merge.

Comment: So how do I implement this statement with C# since you are saying that it uses C# variables from my code?

Comment: Its hard to help without seeing how the data is coming from C# (since you mention its not coming from another table). I imagine you would need to do some string concatenation to build the query. Something like: 
`SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("MERGE INTO dbo.StockDailyData AS Target
USING (VALUES ('" + id + "','" + symbol + "'...'", conn);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to do the pre insert. Check out [Trigger to fire only if a condition is met in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280904/trigger-to-fire-only-if-a-condition-is-met-in-sql-server) .

Comment: So this is only for mysql?