# SQL Server - Update other table only if column values change

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have data streaming from an external program to TABLE1 in my SQL Server database. Let's say TABLE1 consists of columns data1 and data2. How do I update to another table (TABLE2) when a value changes in TABLE1?

For the sake of an example, let's say a value in the data1 column changes.

Note: I wrote a trigger that works, but this is only on the basis of a manual update. I can't figure out how to automate this, meaning the trigger would compare new and old values from the table on its own and then perform the update if a value is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger to fire only if a condition is met in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280904/trigger-to-fire-only-if-a-condition-is-met-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below would work,

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_table1
AFTER UPDATE ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
     IF OLD.val1<> new.val1 THEN
         /**
            -- do operations on table2
        **/ 
     END IF;
END;
```

-- if val1 allows null we need to check by adding more conditions to the if clause like,

```
IF((OLD.val1 IS NULL AND NEW.val1 IS NOT NULL) OR (OLD.val1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.val1 IS NULL) OR (OLD.val1<>NEW.val1)) THEN

/**
-- operations on table2
**/
END IF;
```